# Validation in MVC C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation

I following this tutorial for MVC data validation: http://www.tutorialsteacher.com/mvc/implement-validation-in-asp.net-mvc and somehow this is not working.  Below is my code:

Model:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace LayoutProject.Models
{
    public class Book
    {
        [Required]
        public int bookId { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public String title { get; set; }
        [StringLength(50)]
        public String author { get; set; }
        [Range(0,4)]
        public int publicationYear { get; set; }
        public String editor { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Partial View:

```
@model LayoutProject.Models.Book

<h4>Books</h4>

@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
@Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
@Html.HiddenFor(b => b.bookId)

    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>@Html.LabelFor(d=>d.bookId)</td>
            <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(d=>d.bookId)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(b => b.bookId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>@Html.LabelFor(d=>d.title)</td>
            <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(d=>d.title)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>@Html.LabelFor(d=>d.author)</td>
            <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(d=>d.author)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>@Html.LabelFor(d=>d.publicationYear)</td>
            <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(d=>d.publicationYear)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>@Html.LabelFor(d=>d.editor)</td>
            <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(d=>d.editor)</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

View:

```
    @{
    ViewBag.Title = "CreateBooks";
}

<h2>CreateBooks</h2>

<form action="/Home/SaveBooks" method="post">
    @Html.Partial("_CreateBook")
    <input id="createBook" type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

As you can see, the bookId is a required field, however when I click on the submit button without entering any bookId, I get no error message.  The model would go to the controller and follow any methods written there.  Any idea what I might have missed?

Controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SaveBooks(Book book)
    {
        return View(book);
    }
```

Comment: what is the controller code you have? also you are using a hidden field for book ID - are you sure that the book id is not already populated and is being posted back?

Comment: Why do you have a hidden for and text box for bookID?

Comment: `bookId` is typeof `int` which has a defaut value of `0` which means it has a value when your submit because of your hidden input (its not `null`) so therefore is valid

Comment: And as observed by @hjardine, no matter what you enter in the textbox for `bookid`, it will be ignored because your hidden input is bound to the value and the textbox value is ignored by the `DefaultModelBinder` (only the value of the first input is bound)

Comment: @Ahmed ilyas:  I have added the controller code in my question.

Comment: @Stephen Muecke and hjardine:  Ok, I removed the @Html.HiddenFor(b => b.bookId) in my partial view.  But the error message still won't show.

Comment: so you still need to add code in the controller to check to see if the ModelState is valid and if not, return back to the view. I also think you are looking for client side validation so it prevents submission in which case an answer has also been provided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I can gather there is two scenarios:

1. You pre-fill the `bookId` in the `HiddenFor` and just use this to hold the ID for the form callback

OR

2. The user can fill in the `bookId` using the `TextBoxFor` which isn't bound as the `HiddenFor` occurs first

Solution:

If the case is 1. - Remove `TextBoxFor`, `LabelFor` and `ValidationFor` `bookID` and ensure you are pre-filling the `HiddenFor` correctly (it is int so will always be valid)

If the case is 2. - Remove the `HiddenFor` and you should be fine.

**UPDATE:**
As it is of type `int`, required will always be valid as its default state is 0

If 0 is never valid then you can do something like this:

**In your Model:**

```
[PosNumberNoZero(ErrorMessage = "A positive number, bigger than 0 is required")]
public int bookId { get; set; }

//In the same file:

public class PosNumberNoZeroAttribute : ValidationAttribute {
    public override bool IsValid(object value) {
        if (value == null) {
            return true;
        }
        int getal;
        if (int.TryParse(value.ToString(), out getal)) {

            if (getal == 0)
                return false;

            if (getal > 0)
                return true;
        }
        return false;

    }
}
```

**Update 2:** This is untested but I think you can use:

```
[Range(1, int.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "Please enter a number greater than 0." )]
public int bookId { get; set; }
```

If 0 is valid then swap 1 for 0

Comment: Yes I want to do client side validation only for the moment.  However I tried your 2nd solution and it still does not work.  Also, I am doing the same test with a String.  But the form does not show any error message even when I don't fill the title field, which is a required field too.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you're missing `jquery-validation` and `jquery.validate.unobtrusive` script references. Try to add the following code in your view (or in your layout):

```
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.14.0/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/mvc/5.2.3/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>
```

Of course you can download them and reference them as a local files.

Also small side note - in C# the properties should be named in `PascalCase` (the name should starts with a capital letter and every new word starts with a capital letter).

Answer (score 0):

```
[Integer]
    [Min(1, ErrorMessage="Please enter Valid bookid.")]
    [Required]
public int bookId { get; set; }
```